# life is strange: spinning forever after ch. 1

Tags: life-is-strange

[image]

it has been spinning for the last half-hour, at least.

> Next

> Exit

> Friend Stats

> Refresh

Are all clickable, technically, but do nothing at all - so probably unclickable.

So, what's up - why can't I move on?

Comment: Weirdly, one person [posted on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/319630/discussions/1/598198356198843777/#c598199244888475567) that they unplugged their external hard drive and it got passed the loading.  However, it seems they were stuck at a different point.  If you have any external hard drives or USB sticks plugged in, perhaps remove them quickly and see if that helps.

Comment: @TimmyJim Nothing plugged-in, actually...

Comment: I would say try a restart, but I don't know what amount of progress you will lose from doing that.  Might be risky.

Comment: If I remember right, everything is saved at that point. You'll just have to start next chapter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This screen is just apparently to load percentages of the choice made my all netizens:

[image]

I had to turn on VPN to get the page to load. Basically, I had to quit and restart after turning on the the vpn - if you're in a country that might not be able to access such stats, try the VPN.

Comment: Yikes - what a solution.  It's odd that the game won't display some sort of stats error and move on.  Can you play this offline as well?

Comment: Yeah, offline seems to be fine - it's the first error/problem I've run into.